# SQL ORACLE need assistance-

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL>

```
CREATE TABLE Loan(
    Loan_ID NUMBER (5)
    CONSTRAINT  pk_Loan primary key,
    Start_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    End_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Copy_ID NUMBER(5),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Copy_ID references Copy (Copy_ID),
    customer_ID NUMBER(5),
    CONSTRAINT fk_customer_ID references Customers (Customer_ID),
   Evaluation NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
   check (Evaluation>=0 and Evaluation<=5>);
CONSTRAINT fk_Copy_ID references Copy (Copy_ID),
                                  *
```

ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Have a deeper look at `Evaluation<=5>`

Comment: Also, line 2 missing a comma!

Comment: Also a duplicate constraint fk_Copy_ID.

Comment: @JacobH where do you see that ? I can only see 1 constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please:

```
CREATE TABLE Loan(
    Loan_ID NUMBER (5)
    CONSTRAINT  pk_Loan primary key,
    Start_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    End_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Copy_ID NUMBER(5),
    customer_ID NUMBER(5),
    Evaluation NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Copy_ID foreign key (copy_id) references Copy (Copy_ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_customer_ID foreign key (customer_id) references Customers (Customer_ID),
    constraint chk_evaluation check (Evaluation>=0 and evaluation<=5) );
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you're a life saver